# Date within range?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, date

Given a `MM/DD` date (`12/24`) and a start/end date range (`11/01 - 06/24`), figure out if the date is within the listed date span.

Date ranges can be sequential (`05/01 - 11/01`) or wrap around to the next year (`11/01 - 05/01`).

Examples:

- `12/24` is in `11/01 - 06/24` = True
- `06/24` is in `11/01 - 06/24` = True
- `06/24` is in `06/24 - 06/24` = True
- `06/24` is in `11/01 - 06/23` = False
- `07/24` is in `11/01 - 06/24` = False
- `07/24` is in `05/01 - 11/01` = True
- `07/24` is in `07/23 - 07/20` = True

Years do not mater. The date and/or date range is assumed to apply for any year past or future.

The end date will always be after the start date. If the end date is numerically less than the start date, we assume we are wrapping around to the next year.

The three input variables can be via any method (args, HTTP, stdin, etc..) and in any format (string, JSON, array, etc..)

Response can be `boolean` or any form of a yes/no/correct/etc.. string. Shortest code wins.

You cannot simply pass args to a built-in function.

Comment: Can we take the result as an array of strings instead? I.e `['MM', 'DD']`?

Comment: Test case suggestion: `11/01 - 06/24 includes 06/24?`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder are you picturing something like `['06', '24']` if right else `[]` or what do you mean?

Comment: What is the input format? String, or array of numbers, or array of strings, or array of arrays, or what? Or can we choose among them?

Comment: For your second test case, suppose we're talking this year `2017` and next year `2018`. How are we supposed to determine that `06/24` means `2018` and thus should be `True` rather than `2017` and thus `False` because it's before `11/01`?

Comment: Any special rules for 29 February?

Comment: @Notatree `Unhandled Exception`. Without years I am unable to figure out how one would deal with this. I don't think it's a problem. However, this brings up the question of invalid dates like (`12/65`)

Comment: I'm still not sure your edit about years not mattering answers my question. How are we supposed to know that `06/24` isn't meant to be "before" `11/01` and thus `false`?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork the end date is *always* after the start date. Year does not mater since spans can cross years and all we care about is `date > start & date < end`. The problem is that the numerical values of start and end can be `high,low` or `low,high` (`fall-to-spring` or `spring-to-fall`). See @Arnauld's answer.

Comment: just how flexible is the input format?  eg, could the format be "the number of days since the beginning of the year, so that 1/1 is 1, 1/2 is 2, etc?  if not, what about an array whose first element is the month, 2nd element is day?

Comment: "*`date > start & date < end`*" - Then some of your test cases are wrong. I think what you mean is `start<=date<=end`.

Comment: I think this would be a more interesting challenge if the format was DD/MM instead, because using MM/DD is just comparing plain strings.

Comment: You are correct @Shaggy, `start <= date <= end`

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda a,d,e:(e<d)>=(a<d)+(e<a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHLDoIwEEXX8hUNqxKb0FIfCRGXfoE7JKbQEkkQCMWFX18LNIL1tbqZOXem05nm3l3qiqo8OqmSXVPOAEMciRCKHff2EWRaljpgnuqE7M4Zk0KCCMRO7JLAD1YucgnxMdGKN0N8bG8iQZqb@C@3dOJbk1@P9abPO9dKjeI5pz5e93mjdv1zri/80/z6nQMr5esA1gdnBqtDvzH60zDqZLB3bBkSx8nrVt8sRRnioKjAdKXQWTRtUXUwhwP3EOCeegA)

Takes inputs as  `MM/DD` in order `target, start, end`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
(a%d)e=((e<a)/=(a<d))==(e<d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZC7CsJAEEV7v2IIBmZgJS@jTba1s7MLQQZ3RTGKZGPnv8eNiVFX0epy53DntWNz0GXZNMi@Ii0RdcYUSORMEUlpraJmK9Gn0ZH3J5Bw5PMSztX@VMMYcqzEFhgUaIIrslBCi4qySa1Nvd6w0aaA0dPYfI5eFAfx1BNeFAVhZDWc3f2qumgS@LD/sKMDnvfltEv3XT6w1aTX8AUnQZi25V6d9LDSd/xtcztkwaV5G@5c9uROvn1U8ot3OnD3sW@8aG4)

Thanks to Leo for the trick of xor'ing the Booleans with `/=`.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
(a%d)e=show[e>=d,d>a,a>e]!!16>'a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBDoIwDIbvPEUlGrdkBgaKF@HozZs3QkzjajSCGobx4rsjKIJOo6cv7Zd/7bpFvac0LUuGA8Up1NvjJaYoVEJFKDCipNeTQTTEYbkJ2YBbGe4OEEKGpwWc8t2hgD7ELBcbQFBAHK4MhRIkcj4bFaSL1Ro16QSsrqjyMbOl53hjW9hSOq6s6Ab3epmfiQv2LP9pg62eNu3JI9288qEr@g3dF@077qRuNzTS7Urf9bfNqyFzTPXbcONnnTfy9aH8X/7B1puHffNJeQM)

Comment: Your `show` trick is cool, but you can XOR the three elements in a more direct way with foldl1: https://tio.run/##hZA9D4IwEIZ3f8WFaNImNVDwY7GMbm5uhJiLPaKxfoTi5n9HEAStRqcnd0/e3vV2aA9kTFkyHGlOKjsbbSTzFU8oVlroGAXGlJaZYiM@OOL@BAqOeFnBJd@fChhCwnKRAYIG4nBjKLQgkfPFuCBbbLZoyaYw6IsqnzBPhn448YQnpR/IisHsUa/zK3HBnuU/7bDT87Y9bdLtKx@6YtQyeNGRH0zrdksn3a30XX/bvBqyRGPfhjs/672Trw8V/fINO@8e9s2n5R0

Comment: @Leo Nice idea, it's even shorter expanded out.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>26</s> 20 bytes

```
(a,b,c)=>b>c^b>a^a>c
```

Output is `0` if `a` lies within the range `b`...`c`, `1` if not. Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @nwellnhof.

Comment: What about `(a,b,c)=>b>c^b>a^a>c`?

Comment: @nwellnhof I can't believe I missed that - my very first attempt was `b>a^a>c`, but I then overlooked the simple fix...

Comment: You should update the byte count.

Comment: @nwellnhof Sorry, I was still reeling from the shock!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

Takes input as 3 strings in `MM/DD` format: *date*, *range_from*, *range_to*. Returns a boolean.

```js
(a,b,c)=>!(b<c?a<b|a>c:a<b&a>c)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

(a,b,c)=>!(b<c?a<b|a>c:a<b&a>c)

console.log(f('12/24','11/01','06/24')) // True
console.log(f('06/24','11/01','06/24')) // True
console.log(f('06/24','06/24','06/24')) // True
console.log(f('06/24','11/01','06/23')) // False
console.log(f('07/24','11/01','06/24')) // False
console.log(f('07/24','05/01','11/01')) // True
console.log(f('07/24','07/23','07/20')) // True
```

Comment: Thanks to `MM/DD` format you can just use string sorting. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```hs
(b#e)d=(last$and:[or|b>e])[d>=b,d<=e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNJOVUzxVYjJ7G4RCUxL8UqOr@oJskuNVYzOsXONkknxcY2NfZ/akVibkFOarGCrUK0hpKhkb6RiZKOkqGhvoEhkDYwA/E1dTSgLHwyqDQuPcYQGXOcpkFlDEwhMhAVKDLmIFMgtIGSZiwXV25iZh7Q/bmJBb4KGgVFmXklehoxGik6Ckk6CqmaunaQkNDUVIB79j8A)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Laikoni*

Comment: You can use infix notation to save a byte: `(d#b)e=`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```perl6
{.[0]>.[2]??![>] $_!![<=] $_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BCoMwEETP9StWCRjBSmJbPbSJ/Y8gpSXx1NqiQhHx2@0mevFgD8vs8mYG9mOaZza9eiAViGlIFCtlotKyKHwlSyA331cXYZfRuq4dCKAeDXmaHsMYQs4Zt8oyvKMYidv@kpVuZQ4LyTfbFsJOM3GONcmxZVZmSXT2qndjf9hLoETHQFocE8Hg7dp7DwHR8DDd15gaEdxrjRSEhABtFaXOrl0Eu8bpBw)

Takes a list containing start, date, and end.

-2 bytes thanks to Ramillies.

Comment: And here, you can save 2 bytes by taking 1 list argument instead. Then `@_[0]` can be written as `.[0]` and `[(whatever)] @_` as `[(whatever)] $_`. You just will need to call it like `$f(($s,$d,$e))`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 bytes

59 bytes of code + 1 `-a`

```perl
$F[1]=~s/./2/if$F[1]le$F[0];say($F[2]le$F[1]&&$F[2]ge$F[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLdow1rauWF9P30g/Mw3MzUkFUgax1sWJlRpAlhFEwDBWTQ3MS4dIa/7/b2Cmb2SgYGCkb2SoYGCsb2j0L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dRAA)

Input: *`start_date end_date target_date`*